# Single long running task in each executor

Tags: apache-spark

Sorry if this question looks invalid, I tried to find general guidance to debug task processing times but found nothing yet. I think my problem is a known one, so any help to debug the problem or to understand the problem (related discussion or blog post) would answer my question.

I made multiple streaming spark jobs and almost all of them suffer by same problem; one task in each executor take much longer time than all other tasks:

[image: Tasks time distribution]

But input size of tasks are not that different:
[image: Part of task details]

My workflow is flat mapping (`mapParitionsWithPair ( flatMap )`) over direct Kafka stream source with forty partitions to generating more objects from events and then reducing them (`reduceByKey`) and saving aggregated values to some DB:

[image]

The task timeline figure is for reduce stage.

It's a Apache Mesos based cluster with two nodes and two cores for each node and second stage of all jobs have this uneven task processing time distribution.

**Update**:

- I replaced `reduceByKey` by Java reduce operation (Actually Kotlin Sequence operations) and still same problem occurs.
- After replaying job I realized this problem does harm that much for bigger inputs; It processes 160K events in 1.8 to 4.8 minutes (worse case 580 events per second) and while there is still some tasks taking much longer time, the final effect is much less harmful than for small inputs whose processing rate is between 660 to 54. Interestingly for both cases long running tasks get same amount of time (about 41 seconds)
- Problem exists even after increasing RAM. Executors now have %30 free RAM.

**Update**:

I changed workflow to not shuffle data by using Java 8 Stream reduce in each partition. Here is changed job's DAG:

[image: Changed Job DAG to not shuffle data]

I increased batch interval to 20 seconds and added more nodes; Now, there is not just one slow tasks but more slow tasks and few faster ones, but:

1. Now it is overally doing much faster than previous version with shorter intervals
2. I expect CPU usage always be high, specially for operation in mapPartition, but It's not always true.

[image: Task follow for changed job to use Stream reduce operation in each partition]

Just put some logging around actual operation in each partition and I see strangely sometimes tasks are slow and sometimes is fast. When task is going on slow, CPU is idle and I can't see any blocking by network or CPU I/O. Memory usage is constant at %50. Here is mentioned executor logs:

```
started processing partitioned input: thread 99
started processing partitioned input: thread 98
finished processing partitioned input: thread 99 took 40615ms
finished processing partitioned input: thread 98 took 40469ms
started processing partitioned input: thread 98
started processing partitioned input: thread 99
finished processing partitioned input: thread 98 took 40476ms
finished processing partitioned input: thread 99 took 40523ms
started processing partitioned input: thread 98
started processing partitioned input: thread 99
finished processing partitioned input: thread 98 40465ms
finished processing partitioned input: thread 99 40379ms
started processing partitioned input: thread 98
finished processing partitioned input: thread 98 468
started processing partitioned input: thread 99
finished processing partitioned input: thread 99 525
started processing partitioned input: thread 99
started processing partitioned input: thread 98
finished processing partitioned input: thread 98 738
finished processing partitioned input: thread 99 790
started processing partitioned input: thread 98
finished processing partitioned input: thread 98 took 558
started processing partitioned input: thread 99
finished processing partitioned input: thread 99 took 461
started processing partitioned input: thread 98
finished processing partitioned input: thread 98 took 483
started processing partitioned input: thread 99
finished processing partitioned input: thread 99 took 513
started processing partitioned input: thread 98
finished processing partitioned input: thread 98 took 485
started processing partitioned input: thread 99
finished processing partitioned input: thread 99 took 454
```

Above logs is just for mapping some incoming inputs to objects for saving in Cassandra, and does not include time for saving to Cassandra; here is logs for save operation which is always fast and don't leave CPU idle:

```
18/02/07 07:41:47 INFO Executor: Running task 17.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 207)
18/02/07 07:41:47 INFO TorrentBroadcast: Started reading broadcast variable 5
18/02/07 07:41:47 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_5_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 7.8 KB, free 1177.1 MB)
18/02/07 07:41:47 INFO TorrentBroadcast: Reading broadcast variable 5 took 33 ms
18/02/07 07:41:47 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_5 stored as values in memory (estimated size 16.4 KB, free 1177.1 MB)
18/02/07 07:41:47 INFO BlockManager: Found block rdd_30_2 locally
18/02/07 07:41:47 INFO BlockManager: Found block rdd_30_17 locally
18/02/07 07:42:02 INFO TableWriter: Wrote 28926 rows to keyspace.table in 15.749 s.
18/02/07 07:42:02 INFO Executor: Finished task 17.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 207). 923 bytes result sent to driver
18/02/07 07:42:02 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 209
18/02/07 07:42:02 INFO Executor: Running task 18.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 209)
18/02/07 07:42:02 INFO BlockManager: Found block rdd_30_18 locally
18/02/07 07:42:03 INFO TableWriter: Wrote 29288 rows to keyspace.table in 16.042 s.
18/02/07 07:42:03 INFO Executor: Finished task 2.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 203). 1713 bytes result sent to driver
18/02/07 07:42:03 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 211
18/02/07 07:42:03 INFO Executor: Running task 21.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 211)
18/02/07 07:42:03 INFO BlockManager: Found block rdd_30_21 locally
18/02/07 07:42:19 INFO TableWriter: Wrote 29315 rows to keyspace.table in 16.308 s.
18/02/07 07:42:19 INFO Executor: Finished task 21.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 211). 923 bytes result sent to driver
18/02/07 07:42:19 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 217
18/02/07 07:42:19 INFO Executor: Running task 24.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 217)
18/02/07 07:42:19 INFO BlockManager: Found block rdd_30_24 locally
18/02/07 07:42:19 INFO TableWriter: Wrote 29422 rows to keyspace.table in 16.783 s.
18/02/07 07:42:19 INFO Executor: Finished task 18.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 209). 923 bytes result sent to driver
18/02/07 07:42:19 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 218
18/02/07 07:42:19 INFO Executor: Running task 25.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 218)
18/02/07 07:42:19 INFO BlockManager: Found block rdd_30_25 locally
18/02/07 07:42:35 INFO TableWriter: Wrote 29427 rows to keyspace.table in 16.509 s.
18/02/07 07:42:35 INFO Executor: Finished task 24.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 217). 923 bytes result sent to driver
18/02/07 07:42:35 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 225
```

Comment: @user8371915: `{acc: Tuple2<Int, Int> , rE: Tuple2<Int, Int> -> Tuple2(acc._1 + rE._1, acc._2 + rE._2)}`

Comment: We need more information to help. Which Stage are these tasks a part of? How many partitions our outputted from `reduceByKey`? Might there be any skewing related to your keys? Show us your Spark DAG.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I think I already shared those information.. It's for second stage (3317) of above DAG (third figure). `reduceByKey` partitions count is forty, default for Kafka with forty partitions. Increasing paritions for `reduceByKey` to 200 didn't change long running task's processing time. I see no skewed data according to output size in second figure.

Comment: It seems like these tasks are just hitting GC cycles. How big is your executor heap?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Executor memory is 1GB and heap size is 381MB. You can see the amount of input data is not so big, neither is DAG complexity. GC time for those tasks are small too.

Comment: I agree that this is generally taking too much time, thats why we need to see your actual code and not only the DAG metadata